# Python O365 Outlook Connection Issues

Tags: python, azure, azure-active-directory, o365-flow

I am trying to write a script in Python to grab new emails from a specific folder and save the attachments to a shared drive to upload to a database. Power Automate would work, but the file size limit to save the attachment is a meager 20 MB. I am able to authenticate the token, but am getting the following error when trying to grab the emails:

Unauthorized for url.
The token contains no permissions, or permissions can not be understood.

I have included the code I am using to connect to Microsoft Graph.

(credentials and tenant_id are correct in my code, took them out for obvious reasons

```
from O365 import Account, MSOffice365Protocol, MSGraphProtocol

credentials = ('xxxxxx', 'xxxxxx')  
protocol = MSGraphProtocol(default_resource='reporting.triometric@xxxx.com')  
scopes_graph = protocol.get_scopes_for('message_all_shared')  
scopes = ['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']  
account = Account(credentials, auth_flow_type='credentials', tenant_id="**", scopes=scopes,)  


if account.authenticate():  
print('Authenticated')  
mailbox = account.mailbox(resource='reporting.triometric@xxxx.com')  
inbox = mailbox.inbox_folder()  
for message in inbox.get_messages():  
print(message)
```

I have already configured the permissions through Azure to include all the necessary 'mail' delegations.

The rest of my script works perfectly fine for uploading files to the database. Currently, the attachments must be manually saved on a shared drive multiple times per day, then the script is run to upload. Are there any steps I am missing? Any insights would be greatly appreciated!

Here are the permissions:[image]

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the permissions you added in app registration?

Comment: I have added the permissions set up for this app registration, thanks for looking!

Comment: Hi did you look into my answer? Is there any update?

Comment: Thanks for the help Allen! My organization does not allow any of the permissions in the Application menu, so I have changed the auth_flow_type to 'Authorization' so the token is issued through the web, but am still waiting on approval for those permissions to be approved by the IT team.

Comment: If you use `Authorization` that means it's using auth code flow. In this case delegated permission is correct. I'll update the answer. If it's helpful, you can mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`auth_flow_type='credentials'` means you are using client credentials flow.

In this case you should add **Application permissions** rather than Delegated permissions.

[image: See [permissions][1]:]

Don't forget to click on "Grant admin consent for {your tenant}".

**UPDATE:**

If you set auth_flow_type to 'Authorization', it will use auth code flow which requires the delegated permission.